# Can you set ADFS to automatically redirect to the login page when a user receives an error?

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, adfs3.0

Currently I'm trying to get Salesforce to hook up with an ADFS cluster. I have it working, but I notice when users go to their bookmarked Salesforce pages without first logging in to ADFS (that are saved *past* the login point of their journey through the site) they receive a general ADFS error

> An error occurred. Contact your administrator for more information.

I think this error is expected since they aren't authenticated with ADFS yet.

However, when they receive this error, is there a way to have them automatically be redirected to the login page on ADFS to log into Salesforce? I want to enhance their experience so they don't see errors so much.

ADFS is on Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Salesforce supports SP initiated & IDP initiated flows. This error in SP initiated case is not expected. There should be an activity/correlation ID that is shown as "details" in the page. Could you track down the corresponding event on the ADFS server and investigate. If you can't figure out the problem from the even message, tweet me @MrADFS and I'll come back to this thread to look at the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by ensuring the Salesforce custom domain was published to all users and that bookmark settings were properly set.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_name_testing_and_rollout.htm&language=en_US

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_name_login_id_prov.htm&language=en_US